# How to calculate the interaction of a two level system with a chirp femsecond pulse using the time-dependent Schordinger equation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, semiclassical

I want to calculate the absorption spectra of a two level system interacting with a chirped femtosecond pulse, I don't know how to include chirp into the interaction. In my present calculation, I only include the envelope of a Fourier transformed pulse in to the interaction Hamiltonian 
$$
H_\mathrm{int}=\mu E_0  (\Theta(t+T)-\Theta(t))\cos^2(\pi t/T),
$$
where $T$ is the pulse duration $\Theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, and $\mu$ is the dipole moment of the transition. I am really confused about how to include the chirp of the pulse when calculating. Please help me!

Comment: You can add a time-dependent phase e.g. $\cos^2 (\pi t/T + c t^2)$.

Comment: Do you mean a modification of the  shape of time-domain envelop of the pulse and I can just leave out the $e^{i\omega t}$ oscillation under the envelop? Do I need to use a time-dependent dipole moment?

Comment: Your chirp is basically a time dependent phase shift that you add to the argument of your carrier wave. Plot the function I posted in my first comment and you'll see what I mean. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp

Comment: Sorry, I find I have give the wrong $H_{int}$, it should be $H_{int}=\mu E_0 (\Theta(t+T)-\Theta(t))\cos^2(\pi t/T) $

Comment: The $\cos^2(\pi t/T)$ is the shape of the envelop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *strongly* hesitate to call your current setup a femtosecond pulse, because it's missing an absolutely vital ingredient ─ the carrier frequency. The hamiltonian should always read in the form
$$H_\mathrm{int}=\mu E_0  (\Theta(t+T)-\Theta(t))\cos^2(\pi t/T)\cos(\omega t+\varphi_\mathrm{CE}),$$
where $\omega$ is the carrier frequency, $\varphi_\mathrm{CE}$ is the carrier-envelope phase, and $\cos(\omega t+\varphi_\mathrm{CE})$ is the term that actually drives the dynamics.

If you then want to include chirp, you just add a quadratic phase term to the carrier's oscillations:
$$H_\mathrm{int}=\mu E_0  (\Theta(t+T)-\Theta(t))\cos^2(\pi t/T)\cos(\omega t+\varphi_\mathrm{CE}+\beta\,(t-T/2)^2).$$

Comment: Thanks, I have to think about something really carefully, I'm dizzy now.